# Question About $E=hf$

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, physical-constants

Einstein's famous equation starts out as $E=hf$. He was the first person to boldly intertwine Planck's Constant with the energy of electromagnetic waves.

If we factor the speed of light out of Planck's Constant, we get the following equation with the following constant:

$$E=(2.210\cdot{}10^{-42}kg\cdot{}m)cf$$

If we factor the Planck Length out of that resulting constant, we get the following equation with the following constant:

$$E=(1.36\cdot{}10^{-7}kg)l_pcf$$

And if we factor the Plank Mass out of that resulting constant, we get the following equation with the following unit-less constant:

$$E=6.25m_pl_pcf$$

Finally, we now recognize that $6.25$ is wonderfully close to $2\pi$. So we end up with the following:

$$E=2\pi m_pl_pcf$$

I've never seen this anywhere before, but then, I'm not very well travelled in the world of particle physics. It seems like a very nice equation though. I guess I'm just wondering if anyone has seen Einstein's Nobel Prize equation expressed this way before. How could we interpret this equation as it relates to the energy of electromagnetic waves?

If we rearrange it as follows we might think of something:

$$E=m_p(2\pi cf)l_p$$

That's in a $Force\times{Distance}$ configuration where we'd be accelerating a Planck Mass at a rate defined by $2\pi cf$ over a distance equal to the Planck Length.

Or, if we rearrange it as follows we get a kinetic style to it where $f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$:

$$E=\frac{2\pi l_p}{\lambda}{m_p}{c^2} $$

A Planck Mass is moving at speed $c$ with that kinetic energy. The familiar prefix of $\frac{1}{2}$ appears to be gone.

The "work version" with the $2\pi cf$ acceleration is pretty interesting to me. That acceleration could also be expressed as $2\pi\lambda f^2$. What would cause such an acceleration? A gravitational field could cause an acceleration and then we'd have such an equation that makes use of a "virtual mass" at some distance from the Planck Mass discussed above:

$$2\pi cf = \frac{Gm_v}{r_v^2}$$

And if we plug in some reasonable numbers we could possibly get a qualitative feel for this. Using a gamma ray frequency and the mass of the sun we get:

$$2\pi(2.998\times 10^8\frac{m}{s})(4.0\times 10^{19}Hz) = \frac{(6.67408\times10^{-11}\frac{m^3}{kg\cdot{s^2}})(1.989\times10^{30}kg)}{r_v^2}$$

Solving for $r_v$ we get:

$$r_v = 4.197\times10^{-5}m$$

To me, that's pretty incredible. If you want to accelerate a Plank Mass at a rate of $2\pi cf$, based on a gamma ray frequency, then you'd need a sun-sized mass at an extremely short distance away from the Plank Mass in order to accomplish it.

Comment: *"He was the first person to boldly intertwine Planck's Constant with the energy of electromagnetic waves."* Well, except for Planck. I mean, Planck left room for it to be a feature of the production rather than intrinsic, but this was exactly what he did in suggesting a solution to the ultraviolet catastrophe.

Comment: You are attempting numerology without understanding the physics.

Comment: Please read our [FAQ on writing good question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: @dmckee, Planck did not suggest a solution to the ultraviolet catastrophe. The term did not exist back then, it was introduced years later by Ehrenfests. Planck did derive Planck spectral function in various ways, but in none did he imply energy of EM waves is quantized in units of $hf$.

Comment: @JonCuster: this is a good training with the constants that must be done at least once. Compton probably built scattering starting with constants game :)

Comment: "Wonderfully close" is not close enough.  For example, the fine structure constant is wonderfully close to $(1^2 + 6^2 + 10^2)^{-1}$,  and $\pi$ is wonderfully close to $22/7$, and $g$ is wonderfully close to $\pi^2$.  These are of no consequence, although the last one may have some history.  It's even more compelling when it is close when it's supposed to be equal.  Lesson: don't truncate prematurely!

Answer (score 12):

You have discovered that
$$h = 2 \pi m_p l_p c.$$
However, this isn't very surprising, because the Planck units $m_p$ and $l_p$ are defined in terms of $h$ and $c$ to begin with. We have
$$m_p = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}}, \quad l_p = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}.$$
Multiplying these together, we have
$$m_p l_p = \frac{\hbar}{c} = \frac{h}{2\pi c}$$
which is equivalent to your formula.

I would advice against trying to tell stories involving Planck units, in order to interpret $E = hf$. That's because $E = hf$ is *more* fundamental than any of the Planck units; it tells us how energy and time are related in quantum mechanics in the first place. That is, intuitive interpretations of the Planck time follow from the fact that $E \sim hf$ in quantum mechanics, not the other way around.

Comment: I think your comment about how time and energy are related is extremely interesting.